# Simple Math Expression in ExprTk

Tags: c++, exprtk

I am attempting to use a simple expression such as the following and the result should be that the value of z becomes 1. However nothing seems to be happening any suggestions on how I could resolve this issue ?

```
template<typename t>
void MyTestB()
{

    t x = 1.0;
    t z = 0;

    std::string e = "if((x + 2) == 3){z=1;}";
    exprtk::symbol_table<t> symbol_table;
    symbol_table.add_variable("x",x);
    symbol_table.add_variable("z",z);

    exprtk::expression<t> expression;
    expression.register_symbol_table(symbol_table);


    exprtk::parser<t> parser;

    parser.compile(e,expression);
    t y = expression.value();
    std::cout << z;
}
```

The program does finish however at y = NAN (which is understandable because expression is a conditional statement) However z still remains 0. I was expecting it to become 1

Comment: "nothing seems to be happening" is a somewhat vague problem description. How do you call this function? Do you get wrong outpu or no output at all? Does the program finish or hang?

Comment: Does it work without templates?  (e.g. fix `t` as `int`)

Comment: Just glancing at the examples online, it looks like your string should look like: "if((x+2) == 3, z := 1, 0)". Have you tried something like that?

Comment: @Taylor yes that did the trick. Could you put that in the answe

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looking at [the examples](http://partow.net/programming/exprtk/), it appears that `if` statements should have the form:

`if (condition, expression if true, expression if false)`

Also, assignment uses `:=` instead of just `=`. So you should use the string:

`if((x + 2) == 3, z := 1, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

The expression when written out with proper indentation like so:

```
if( (x + 2) == 3 )
{
  z=1;
}
```

The issue is the value of the consequent statement: "z=1".

The `=` here is ***not*** assignment but rather equality *(aka '==' ).*

Hence the actual result of the if statement when the condition is true is **false** which converts to **zero**.

**Note:** Section 12.3 of the readme documentation details the how the conditional statements operate.